# difference between Nested Cross Validation and Hold-one-Out

Tags: cross-validation

I understand that for small sample sizes its best not to opt for the traditional hold out validation but rather use the entire dataset and perform a k-fold cross-validation. However in my case i want to find the best hyper-parameters and select the best model, i understand that in this case a nested cross validation may be the better option.

If I understand the method of nested cross validation, i.e. take your entire dataset and split it into 2 folds. You then take each fold and perform a k-fold cross validation to determine best hyper-parametes on one fold. And for the other fold you perform a k-fold cross validation to determine the best model. Is my understanding of cross validation correct
 and if so how is this any different to hold one validation?

Comment: I still didnt get the second part. You are splitting your data into 2 sets to do a k-fold cv on each?
This would not be "nested" CV, only 2 CVs.
In nested CV, there is an outer loop and an inner loop. The inner part is usually to fit a model and the outer is for hyperparameter tuning.

In contrast, the Hold-Out method reserves a certain amount for testing (1/3) and uses the remainder for training (2/3).

Comment: Thanks @Inathan, i understand that but i fail to see how nested cross validation methods works to ensure that the inner loop does not leak data into the outer loop during training  - does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamentally misunderstood the concept of cross validation.

- **$k$-fold cross validation:** Have 1 loop

  - Equally divide dataset into $k$ folds.
  - For $i \in [1;k]$, test models on the $i$-th fold and train on the remaining folds.
  - The final result is the average results of $k$ testing folds.
- **nested $k$-fold cross validation:** Have 2 loops.

  - For every $i$ above, we have a $k$-fold cross validation nested inside.
- **Holdout:** literally hold a set of data out for testing.

In your case, when you split the data into 2 folds and **perform two different tasks on each fold**, you are not doing cross validation. The key thing to remember that whatever you want to do, you have perform it independently for every $i \in [1;k]$.

Thus, in your case, the correct way should be:

- In the inner loop, you select best hyper-parameters by subsequently using different hyper-params to train model on the inner training folds and test on the inner testing fold.
- Then use the best models selected in the inner loop to test on the outer loop.
- The average results of the outer loop is the estimated performance of your model.